# A live-action show where a family adopts a group of colorful slimes

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am trying to remember a live-action show or miniseries I saw in Russia in the late 80s. The show was being translated from another language, most likely French. It could have also been a multi part movie. Russian TV was often confusing with that. Being shown in Russia may mean that the show was also old, but it had to be popular enough to import.

In it a family, parents and kids, ends up with a group of colorful slimes. The slimes were some sort of simple special effects, and mostly communicated through just shapes in their petri dishes. The show would often show them bubbling up and down.  The slimes were maybe about the size of a baseball each, and usually stayed in place.

The show's main hijinks were about the lab or government or something trying to get the slimes back.
The slimes had electrical powers. They could absorb electricity and do things with it, a fact that would often save the day. There were often shots in the show of electricity arching between all the slimes.

The show was family programming. It was not a comedy, and had some tense moments about bad things happening to the slimes, but was always kid friendly.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: You say colorful slimes and I think of the [Barbapapas](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/By83XPPOxsA/hqdefault.jpg), but they were a bit taller than baseballs, and it's too childish to feature government-chase, I think. But maybe you could find yours in some kind of "related works" list or something :)

Comment: @Jenayah the show was live action, and judging by the art did not share any themes, so i think that is pretty far off

Comment: Not "Under the Mountain", which had larger slimes, who were the enemy.

Comment: You do have to wonder how the merchandising was handled.